# asp.net mvc search by relationships in linq to sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How to select in data which i need in the relationship. In this code my searching is worked

```
 var   teachers = db.teachers.Where(a => a.Groups.Any(g => g.id == groupid)).ToList();
```

But this code return teachers with all their groups. I need select groups which have id=groupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to project your query to get only the groups that meet that condition. I suggest to create a custom class to fetch only the data you need:

```
public class TeacherDTO
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Group> Groups{get;set;}
  //...
}
```

So, your query could be like this:

```
var   teachers = db.teachers.Where(a => a.Groups.Any(g => g.id == groupid))
                            .Select(a=>new TeacherDTO
                                           {
                                            Id=a.id, 
                                            Groups=a.Groups.Where(g=>g.id==groupid)
                                           })
                            .ToList();
```